# What should happen so that η-reduction suddenly appear in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Suppose I have `def f(a); a + 1; end` and apply `f` to List it usually looks like `[1,2,3].map { |x| f x }`.

And when I want to use η-reduction (`(λx.Mx) → M`), I've got an error here:

```
> [1,2,3].map f
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
    from (irb):2:in `f'
    from (irb):4
    from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

What should happen so that it became a valid Ruby syntax?

Answer (score 3):

```
[1, 2, 3].map &method(:f)
=> [2, 3, 4]
```

See [`Object#method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-method).

Answer (score 2):

Map expects a block.  You could do something like this if you wanted:

```
f = lambda { |a| a+1 }
[1,2,3].map &f
```

This way you are passing the block as an argument.  In order to pass blocks via arguments you need to use the & sign.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this:

```
print (1..3).collect{|i| i+1}  #=> [2, 3, 4]
```

Alternatively this too:

```
(1..3).map(&:succ)  #=> [2, 3, 4]
```